# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input when fetching JSON in a local enviroment

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have a webpage that fetches information about products from a JSON file in my computer. The problem is that when `.json()` gets executed, I get the error `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`. This only happens if I run the webpage directly in the file system (opening the .html file) while, in the other hand, if I run the webpage in a server It works properly. Someone can tell me why and how to fix this issue?

```js
async function obtener (url) {
  if (typeof(url) !== 'string') return
  const respuesta = await fetch(url, {
    mode: "no-cors",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    }
  })
  return respuesta.json() // error is thrown here
}

const productosURL = './datos/merchandising.json'
const productos = await obtener(productosURL)
```

JSON file:

```json
[
    {
        "id": "ee154f46-10d4-4007-9ecf-44332bc45346",
        "nombre": "Camiseta Prematch - 2023",
        "categoria": "Hombre Fútbol",
        "precio": 11000,
        "disponible": true,
        "imgURL": "./recursos/img/productos/futbolprematch2023.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": "4d20afcc-516d-4118-8b34-6cd17c17772c",
        "nombre": "Camiseta Titular - 2023",
        "categoria": "Hombre Fútbol",
        "precio": 15000,
        "disponible": true,
        "imgURL": "./recursos/img/productos/futbol-titular2023.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": "778f7c59-4e9d-45a6-8b2e-2f9cb466476b",
        "nombre": "Camiseta Alternativa - 2023",
        "categoria": "Hombre Fútbol",
        "precio": 9000,
        "disponible": true,
        "imgURL": "./recursos/img/productos/futbol-alternativa2023.jpg"
    }
]
```

Project's file structure. I run the webpage by opening merchandising.html (no server running)

[image: structure of this project]

Comment: *"This only happens if I run the webpage directly in the file system (opening the .html file)"* - I'd expect AJAX operations to fail in that scenario.  It sounds like the test itself is invalid in this case.  (Surely there's a duplicate I'm just not finding about AJAX requests to/from the file system...)

Comment: Do you understand `mode: "no-cors"`. JavaScript can't access the body of the response.

Comment: @David as you commented above, I haven't found a question with this particular scenario (request in the file system). I don't know why this has been closed, related questions don't satisfy this issue, though, I understand the "no-cors" now.

Comment: @LucasDavidFerrero: What exactly is left to be satisfied for the issue?  If you're trying to make an AJAX request to the file system then you can't do that.  A file system is not a web server.  In the question it sounds like the functionality works as expected when using a web server, so then is that not the solution?

Comment: (It *does* appear that the first duplicate is incorrect.  There was likely confusion about what "local file" means.  I haven't found a better duplicate yet, though I'm sure there are many.  The bottom line is that making an AJAX request to the file system is simply wrong.)

Comment: Ok. I wasn't aware of that limitation (or purpose) of fetch and XMLHttpRequest APIs. I would research for another browser API to satisfy this need. Thanks for your time @David

Comment: To make it short: You won't find one. It's a security risk and modern browsers won't allow it.